# Rails3 and forum plugin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forum

I'am looking for a good Forum plugin running under rails3 ?

If you have any idea, i'll be glad to hear it :)

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Why does it have to run under Rails3 and not Rails2?

Comment: I assume you do realize Rails 3 has not been released yet.

Comment: Rails3 should be released soon and i'm migrating an application from rails2 to rails3 :)
So it was by curiosity that i was asking for :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably quicker to develop your own than to adapt and upgrade one of the existing Rails forums. There aren't many Rails forum projects as compared to PHP (for example), as it's generally pretty quick to write your own, depending on how many features you need. :)

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer.
Finally i decided to write my own plugin and it does all i needed !
:)

Comment: Did you open source your plugin ?

Comment: I've started to create my own RoR forum plugin named Forumally, but it's in early development.

Answer (score 0):

I started to develop one too in rails 3. It's going to be similar to Wordpress Ideas. Right now i have build the user part with devise and integrated angularjs. I just started. If you are interested in contributing you can find it here: https://github.com/Chocksy/opiniodev-rails-app